# How would I create geofences using an array of information?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cllocation

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial) on setting up geofences for locations but I want to create geofences using an array of information I have grabbed from my Firebase Database. Does anyone know how I would do that or have any tutorials they could link for me? I'm struggling to wrap my head around how I would do this as I'm pretty new to Swift. Could someone help explain what I would do or point me to someone/somewhere that could explain this?

Comment: What's in the database?  Is it latitude/longitude?  You generally need a point and a radius to make a geofence.

Comment: The Database has latitude + longitude along with the radius and an identifier for the region. Thanks for the example below, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
func startMonitoring(_ manager:CLLocationManager, region:CLCircularRegion) {
    if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
        print("Cannot monitor location")
        return
    }
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways {
        print("Please grant access")
    } else {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }
}

func getRegionForLocation(_ location:CLLocation) -> CLCircularRegion {
    let radiusMeters:Double = 1000
    let identifier = "MyGeofence \(location)"

    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: location.coordinate, radius: radiusMeters, identifier: identifier)

    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = !region.notifyOnEntry

    return region
}

func getLocationsFromFireBase() -> [CLLocation] {
    var locations:[CLLocation] = []

    // .. populate with locations from DB

    return locations
}


//where you want to enable
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

let locations = getLocationsFromFireBase()

for location in locations {
    let region = getRegionForLocation(location)
    startMonitoring(locationManager, region: region)
}
```

I am glossing over how to enable location access (you have to add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your info.plist for example), but the general principles of adding multiple geofences is shown.  You also need to add a delegate to the CLLocationManager so you are notified when the device goes into or out of a geofence.